# Velocity Template File Resource Loader not working

Tags: java, velocity

Facing some weird issue,
setting up Velocity Engine like this.

```
 Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.setProperty(RuntimeConstants.EVENTHANDLER_INCLUDE,IncludeRelativePath.class.getName());

    properties.setProperty(RuntimeConstants.RESOURCE_LOADER, "file");
    properties.setProperty("classpath.resource.loader.class", ClasspathResourceLoader.class.getName());
    File f = new File(".");
    LOGGER.info("Base class path : {}",f.getCanonicalPath());
    //Objects.requireNonNull(resource);
    properties.setProperty(Velocity.FILE_RESOURCE_LOADER_PATH,f.getCanonicalPath());
    VelocityEngine velocityEngine = new VelocityEngine();
    velocityEngine.init(properties);
    return velocityEngine;
```

Then I am trying to fetch the file created using :

```
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(templateName+".vm");
        out.println(fileContentStr);
        out.close();
```

like this :

```
Template t = this.getEngine().getTemplate(  fileName + ".vm");
```

This gives me ResourceNotFoundException. It works in my local. I am not hardcoding the path anywhere. Not able to understand why it is not working. Please can someone try to help me out here. I am stuck after trying all permutation combination.

Motive : I just need to be able to read the VM file from project directory and create one.

Comment: The line `properties.setProperty("classpath.resource.loader.class", ClasspathResourceLoader.class.getName());` is useless, it should be `properties.setProperty("file.resource.loader.class", FileResourceLoader.class.getName());`. It works at least locally because that's the default value for this property, that's not the cause of the problem.

Comment: Another remark: the `IncludeRelativePath` purpose is to let #include() and #parse() find templates in the same directory as the current template. It does not apply to your  use case.

Comment: @ClaudeBrisson given all the point . I also would like to ask is does the template name correct? because in windows templatename case insensitive others not . What if the production is not windows?

Comment: @soorapadman You are right, case sensitivity must be checked. I add it to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are certain that the working directory does not change between the time the template is built and the time it is read, then you **don't need to set any property** before initializing Velocity:

- you don't need the `IncludeRelativePath` because its purpose is to let #include() and #parse() find templates in the same directory as the current template. It does not apply to your use case.
- you don't need to set the `file` resource loader because it's the default.
- you certainly don't need to set the class of the `classpath` resource loader because you're not even using it
- you don't need to set the file resource loader path, because it defaults to ".".

I don't know why your code works locally and not into production. Maybe the working directory is changed. Maybe the variables `templateName` and `fileName` aren't consistent. Maybe the template is asked for before it is written. Are there any major differences between the environments? Any security issue? Are the operating systems the same? As soorapadman pointed out, it can be an issue with case sensitivity between linux and Windows.

The following code should work everywhere:

```
VelocityEngine velocityEngine = new VelocityEngine();
velocityEngine.init();
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter("test.vm");
out.println("hello");
out.close();
Template template = velocityEngine.getTemplate("test.vm");
```

Comment: There are changes in environment. I am using Linux locally and creating the file in the project directory. While in server we are using Kubernetes, so when i am trying to do ".".getCanonicalPath() it gives me "/" while when i use ec2 it gives me proper spring/boot path and hence the template gets found. Has anyone faced this?. Also if i am using the File Resource Loader and ClasspathResourceLoader then will my engine read from both the places?

Comment: To use both classloaders, you must set `resource.loader = file, classpath` (or the other way around depending on the priority you want) and then specify the their properties: `file.resource.loader.class`, `file.resource.loader.path` (which can contain several paths), and `classpath.resource.loader.class`.